# Arch Linux LXC Container unable to start

Tags: containers, archlinux, lxc, linux-containers

I am running lxc containers from an Ubuntu host, but the container that has Arch Linux installed will not start up.

The container gets created correctly using this command: `sudo lxc-create -n name -t download -- -d archlinux -r current -a amd64`, but when running `sudo lxc-start -n name`, the container does not start. There is no error message.

Attached is a screenshot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt67Y.png)

the exit status of lxc-start is 0

I tried:

- re-creating the container
- updating lxc on the host system
- rebooting my host system
- checking the disk space of my host system